# In primefaces template all layout get refreshed

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces with template which has header layout, center layout, footer layout
all the layout are gets refreshed simultaneously if i navigated to some other pages.
can anyone give solution for this, i need to update only the center layout without affecting header,footer.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information especially code. Maybe you do not update your center layout but everything instead because you did not use the `update` tag properly? You have to give your center layout an id like

```
<p:panel id="centerPanel">
    //Your centerPanel code here
    <p:commandButton update="@parent" +other attributes />
</p:panel>
```

You can also put the button outside your layout (in my case `p:panel`) and address your layout through `update="centerPanel"`.

Comment: I have used header xhtml file in north layoutunit, footer xhtml file in south layoutunit, in the center layout unit i have added only the form with id specified. in all other pages i am updating every primefaces component using the center layoutunit form id. but it refresh all the layouts including header, footer, center layout.

Rather this i didnt use any component in template.